# OPC UA zombie connection

Tags: python, opc-ua

I recently started working with Yaskawa's OPC UA Server provided on its robot's controller.

I'm connecting to the server via Python's OPCUA library. Everything works well, but when my code crashes or when I will close terminal without disconnecting from the server I cannot connect to it once again.

I receive an error from library, saying:

`The server has reached its maximum number of sessions.`

And the only way to solve this is to restart the controller by turning it off and on again.

Documentation of the server is saying that max number of sessions is 2.

Is there a way to clear the connection to the server without restarting the machine?

Answer (score 1):

The server keeps track of the client session and doesn't know that your client crashed.

But the client can define a short enough SessionTimeout, after which the server can remove the crashed session.

The server may have some custom configuration where you can define the maximum number of sessions that it supports. 2 sessions is very limited, but if the hardware is very limited maybe that is the best you can get. See the product documentation about that.